# Is there a standard way to randomly search my database items with a cron until complete, then reset in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sqlite, screen-scraping

I already have a sceen scraper built using PHP cURL, tied to a mySQL database. I have stored products that need to be updated weekly rather than what I have now (a form that I input the url/product and hit go).

My first thought would be to use standard cron every 30 minutes on a PHP file like so.

I would like to randomize two things, the delay on the PHP script actually accessing the source site (i.e. 0 - 20 minutes) so the process timing is random. Second, I want to access my target items/pages randomly, but be sure to get all of them weekly and/or consistently, before cycling through the list again.

The timer is fairly strait forward and needs no storage of data, but how should I keep track of my items/uri's in this fashion? I was thinking a second cron to clear data, while the first just increments. But still I have to set flags as to what was updated already and I am just not familiar enough for choice of where and how to store this data.

I am using mySQL, with HTML5 options and is on Codeigniter, so can also hold data in SQLite as options..along with cookies if that makes sense. I couple questions on this part, do I query my database (mySQL) for what I need every-time, or do I store on a jSON file once a week, and run that? This obviously depends and/or determines on where I flag what was already processed.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @user1936123 I am updating prices of a product for weekly analysis. This involves scraping and I want this activity to lack any uniformity and avoid excess activity on the URI's I am scraping. So I need to scrape in a random routine if that makes sense. What is hard for me to figure out, is how and where I store the data for the initial trigger. I already have script to populate mySQL when the script is ran, I just need to create a way to update on a regular basis. At this point, I simply enter my item in my form and select go. It does all I want, except make this automated.

Comment: Ah, ok. Reading back through your question, it looks like you have a handle on the delay, but are having trouble with determining which items are due to be scraped at runtime?

Comment: @user1936123 Right. I have to do this randomly, but not duplicate until the list is complete.

Comment: Since you already have a MySQL database with the items that need to be scraped, I would add a field that shows the last time that your item was scraped. Then at runtime, when you query for the items to be scraped in this run, select only the ones that have not been scraped in the last week. Then when you scrape an item, update its last scraped time in your new field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of items to scrape in your MySQL database. Ensure that there is field that holds the last time the item was scraped.

Set a cron job to run every minute with this workflow:

1. Ensure that the previous run of the script has completed (see step #4). If not, end.
2. Check last time you scraped any item.
3. Ensure enough time has passed (see step #9). If not, end.
4. Set a value somewhere to show that you are processing (so step #1 of subsequent runs is aware).
5. Select an item to scrape at random. (from those that haven't been scraped in `n` time.)
6. Delay random interval of seconds to ensure all requests aren't always on the minute.
7. Scrape it.
8. Update time last scraped for that item.
9. Set a random time to wait before next operation (so step #3 of subsequent runs is aware).
10. Set a value to show that you are not processing (so step #1 of subsequent runs is aware).
11. End.

Once all items have been scraped, you can set a variable to hold the time the batch was completed and use it for `n` in step #5.